# Conditional Formatting Error VBA

Tags: excel, vba, formatting, conditional-statements

I was wondering whether someone can help please?! Im getting an error at the following line:

```
.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($E1<>"",AND($E1<TODAY(),$F1=""Awaiting Information"")) = 1"
```

Here is the code below.

```
Sub ConditionalFormat()

Sheets("NACO").Cells.FormatConditions.Delete

 With Worksheets("NACO").Columns("A:N").FormatConditions
**.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($E1<>"",AND($E1<TODAY(),$F1=""Awaiting Information"")) = 1"**
With .Item(.Count).Interior
    .Color = 255
End With

.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($E1<>"",AND($E1<TODAY(),$F1=""On Going"")) = 2"
With .Item(.Count).Interior
    .Color = 225
End With

.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=IF($E1<>"",AND($E1<TODAY(),$F1=""Awaiting Quotation"")) = 3"
With .Item(.Count).Interior
    .Color = 255
End With

.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
    "=$F1=""On Going"" = 4"
With .Item(.Count).Interior
    .Color = RGB(247, 150, 70)
End With
End With
End Sub
```

Could someone please explain why the error is occurring please? Is it to do with the ""?

Comment: `$E1<>""` equates to `$E1<>"` need to double up

Comment: When you try to include literal double-quote characters inside a literal string, you need to double the quotes. So $E`<> "" needs to be $E1<> """"

Comment: Feel a bit of a plank. Its the " " as I thought it would be. Frustrating. Problem I have is its adding the conditional formats but not applying them to the range. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try changing the formula to this one:

`=IF(AND($E1<>"",$E1<TODAY(),$F1="Awaiting Information")=1`?

Comment: Ah so I don't need the IF statement in there if im using an AND / OR?

Comment: @ShawnCartwright, actually I don't know what are your conditions. But probably you are right, see the edited version.